# React useState within mapped parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

Im new to React and im trying to understand useState.
So im pulling in an array of products and then mapping the array to display each product card:

```
export default function ProductList({ products }) {

  return (
        <Grid templateColumns='repeat(3, 1fr)' columnGap={6} rowGap={10}>
          {
            products.map(product => (
              <ProductCard key={product.node.id} product={product} productID={product.node.id} />
            ))
          }
        </Grid>
  )
}
```

and inside of my `ProductCard` I have a bunch of `useState`, to handle product options, variants, etc.

```
const [available, setAvailable] = useState(true)
const [selectedVariant, setSelectedVariant] = useState('')
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState('')
const { addToCart } = useContext(CartContext)
```

So my question is, do each of the `ProductCard` actually share the same useState, even though they are being mapped?

Answer (score 1):

You map collection of separate components, they won't share logic or state. State is hermetic and other components wont have access to it unless allowed to.